# Swift: retrieving data numbers from parse and counting the average value

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, parse-platform

i hope you all doing great :)

my code here retrieve data from classname score, the data is in numbers.
what i'm trying to do is to grab all score values for a particular player and count the average score to be displayed.
i should do it with arrays but i do not know how, i need someone to guide me. Thank you in advance

```
var info = PFQuery(className: "score")
    info.whereKey("player_name", equalTo: player!)
    info.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{

        (objects, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {

            for me in objects! {

                var mine = me.objectForKey("score")
                print(score)


            }

        }else {

            print(error)
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. Just finding the average the old fashioned way.

```
var sum = 0

for me in objects! {
    sum += me.objectForKey("score") as! Int
}

let  avg : Double = Double(sum) / Double(numbers.count)`
```

Answer (score 2):

It should work with the key value coding collection operator `@avg`, just

```
let averageScore = objects!.valueForKeyPath("@avg.score")
```

no repeat loop needed.

Comment: didn't know about about that @avg operator, was going to suggest creating a var variable += score then divide by number of objects, good answer!

Comment: There's a very good article on NSHipster : http://nshipster.com/kvc-collection-operators/

Comment: hi @vadian thank you for your reply. i've tried your suggestion but it returns nil

Answer (score 0):

finally i've found the answer, in case anyone wonder how

```
var sum = 0

            for me in objects! {
                sum += me.objectForKey("score") as! Int
                var number = info.countObjects()
                var average = sum / number
                print(average)
            }
```